# Callback is not function nodejs postgres query

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I am running a postgres query through pg module in nodejs. i want the result rows to be callback. i am getting error, callback is not a function. here is my code.

```
function search(callback) {
    pool.query("Select * from table", function (err, res) {
       callback(res.rows)

    })
}
```

Comment: `callback is not a function` means that `callback` is something other than a function ;)

Comment: Show us the code where you call search()